# How do I search the first column in a datagrid on a user keypress

Tags: wpf, search, datagrid, keypress

I have a wpf application that has a datagrid with names in the first column and additional info in other columns.  The names are in sorted order.  If a user presses a key on the keyboard, say p, I would like the datagrid to go to the first row where the name begins with p.  If the user then presses e, go to the first row that begins with pe, etc.  Is this possible in a datagrid?  I haven't been able to find anything or examples on this.  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For that you should add keydown event.
And Step 1 : OnkeyDown event get text of key.
Step 2 : find item as per your condition from list.
Step 3 : Change selected item.
Step 4 : and scroll datagrid to selected item.

Window keydown event work correctly, in my case datagrid event worked when row was selected.

Here is code.

```
 List<Employee> empData = new List<Employee>();
 private Task task;
 private CancellationToken token;
 private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
 private string searchText = "";
```

KeyDownEvent :

```
    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (task != null && tokenSource != null)
        {
            // cancel task
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Task cancel");
        }

        // Set condition for key
        string txt = new KeyConverter().ConvertToString(e.Key);
        if (txt.ToString().ToList().Any(x => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retrun from.");
            return;
        }

        searchText = searchText + new KeyConverter().ConvertToString(e.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("Search text : " + searchText);

        var item = empData.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.FirstName.StartsWith(searchText));
        if (item != null)
        {
            myGrid.SelectedItem = item;
            myGrid.UpdateLayout();
            myGrid.ScrollIntoView(myGrid.SelectedItem);
        }

        // create task for clean text
        Console.WriteLine("Task generate");
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = tokenSource.Token;
        task = new Task(()=> CleanSearchText(token), token);
        task.Start();

    }
```

Task for clean text after sometime

```
    private void CleanSearchText(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Throw if cancellation request
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // Wait for sometime for next key prss
        Thread.Sleep(400);
        // Do nothing if cancelation request
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Clean text");
        searchText = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. A simple example for Datagrid:
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/
Then handle event keydown in Datagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyDown="DgUsers_OnKeyDown">
```

code behind simple:

```
private void DgUsers_OnKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var row in dgUsers.Items)
            {
                User user = (User) row;
                user.Name = e.Key.ToString();
                dgUsers.SelectedItem = row;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already built in!

```
<DataGrid IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ...
```

Now just let the models "ToString" method return the text you want to search for - done!

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.aspx